# Trying to center an image in a div while using transform origin

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image viewing site and want to be able to get a closer view of a portion of an image while scaling. I am using transform origin to do this and it works well. The problem is that the image veers away from the center of the page and this is a huge problem as I want it centered.
I was able to get it working using img.style.left after scaling but this uses high cpu and I'd rather have everything in one statement.
Trying to figure out what the value of translateX should be. Here is my jsfiddle showing it working ok when using style.left.

https://jsfiddle.net/7bfc1s9w/

To test it, you can simply set transformOriginValues as in:

```
let transformOriginValues = {'x': 1, 'y' : 10};
```

Please not the origin values are in percentages. Use the slider to increase the image size

The challenge is to work exactly the same but to use translate during the scaling/rotating operation.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In css `transform` you can use `translate` along with `scale` and `rotate`. You might try that instead of using `transform-origin` property.

Comment: Hi, I am using transform-origin because when scaling I want  to zoom to a certain area. The zoom is actually supposed to be done with the mouse over an area so that you can get a closer look. The trick is to always keep the image in the center while doing so. I have achieved this by setting img.style.left. Now need to do the same using one translate statement. Thanks